# How to add `style=display:"block"` to an element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to add `style=display:"block"` to an element in jQuery?

Answer (score 404):

```
$("#YourElementID").css("display","block");
```

**Edit:** or as dave thieben points out in his comment below, you can do this as well:

```
$("#YourElementID").css({ display: "block" });
```

Comment: or `.css({ display: "block" });`

Comment: @dave - or `.css({ "display": "block" });` just to short circuit any problems caused by a `display` variable. - JSLint would reject the version without quotes. ( https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/issues/110 )

Comment: The Json-esque asignment is useful to send it down the pipes. I'm liking this.

Answer (score 67):

There are multiple function to do this work that wrote in bottom based on priority.

- ### [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Set one or more CSS properties for the set of matched elements.

```
$("div").css("display", "block")
```

```js
// Or add multiple CSS properties
$("div").css({
  display: "block",
  color: "red",
  ...
})
```

- ### [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Display the matched elements and is roughly [equivalent to calling `.css("display", "block")`](http://api.jquery.com/show/#entry-longdesc)

You can display element using `.show()` instead

```
$("div").show()
```

- ### [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Set one or more attributes for the set of matched elements.

If target element **hasn't `style` attribute**, you can use this method to add inline style to element.

```
$("div").attr("style", "display:block")
```

```js
// Or add multiple CSS properties
$("div").attr("style", "display:block; color:red")
```

- ### JavaScript

You can add specific CSS property to element using **pure javascript**, if you don't want to use jQuery.

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
// One property
div.style.display = "block";
// Multiple properties
div.style.cssText = "display:block; color:red"; 
// Multiple properties
div.setAttribute("style", "display:block; color:red");
```

Answer (score 40):

Depending on the purpose of setting the display property, you might want to take a look at

```
$("#yourElementID").show()
```

and

```
$("#yourElementID").hide()
```

Answer (score 13):

If you need to add multiple then you can do it like this:

```
$('#element').css({
    'margin-left': '5px',
    'margin-bottom': '-4px',
    //... and so on
});
```

As a good practice I would also put the property name between quotes to allow the dash since most styles have a dash in them. If it was 'display', then quotes are optional but if you have a dash, it will not work without the quotes. Anyways, to make it simple: always enclose them in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [BS5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/) and [Tabulator](https://tabulator.info/) I found that I had to add `position: static` to the cell AND add it to the button.

So, I added the following CSS:

```
    .table-responsive .dropdown,
    .table-responsive .btn-group,
    .table-responsive .btn-group-vertical {
        position: static;
    }
```

and on the `Tabulator` div I have:

```
<div id="myTable" class="table-sm table-responsive"></div>
```

and finally on the event I do:

```
myTable.on("dataProcessed", function(data){
  $('[tabulator-field="my_fancy_field"]').css("position", "static");
});
```

You will need some way of finding the right cell. I used the `field` that I am loading the data from.

I then end up with (on most rows) something that looks like this:

[image]

And on the last row it pops upwards like this:

[image]