# Javascript - Add style when we tap on the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nb-team .nb-team-grid').click(function() {
        $(".nb-team-info")
        .css('opacit:1')
    });
});
```

Hey guys, I'm trying to change style when we tap on a div. And it should only happen in mobile resolution. So I tried but its not working, and I have attached my code above. Please go through for more clarification. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post your html as well thank you

Comment: it is not `.css('opacit:1')` it should be `.css('opacity:1')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add \`style=display:"block"\` to an element using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269136/how-to-add-style-displayblock-to-an-element-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add this style only to the mobile or small screen size you can try this.

```js
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nb-team-grid").click(function() {
$(this).next(".nb-team-info").toggleClass("my-class");
         
    });
});

</script>
```

```css
.my-class{  opacity:0;}

.parent-div{background:#eee; width:50%; float:left; height:auto;}

@media (max-width:420px){

    .my-class{
        
       opacity:0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent-div">
<div class="nb-team-grid" style="height:100px; width:100px; background:red;"></div>

<div class="nb-team-info"  style="height:100px; width:100px; background:black;"></div>

</div>


<div class="parent-div">
<div class="nb-team-grid" style="height:100px; width:100px; background:red;"></div>

<div class="nb-team-info"  style="height:100px; width:100px; background:black;></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185134/discussion-on-answer-by-sumit-kumar-javascript-add-style-when-we-tap-on-the-di).

Answer (score 0):

We can add styles through javascript like this

```
 $(".nb-team-info")
        .css('opacity','1');
```

You just have small syntax mistake

EDIT 1

To apply styles only when the resolution for mobile we can check for window width and decide whether to apply the styles or not like this

```
if($(window).width() < 768){
     $(".nb-team-info")
            .css('opacity','1');
}
```

or

Without `javascript` we can do using `media-queries`

```
@media (max-width:420px){

    .nb-team-info{
        opacity : 1
    }
}

@media (min-width:421px){

    .nb-team-info{
        opacity : 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we set this script for mobile resolution?

Comment: Yes we can do that by first checking the width of the window and then applying the styles.

Comment: @Bst_coder I have updated the answer according to your requirements, check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nb-team-grid').click(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 767) {
            $(".nb-team-info").css('opacity', '.5');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should write like this:

```
$('.nb-team-info').css('opacity', '1');
```

or:

```
$('.nb-team-info').attr('style', 'opacity: 1');
```

Answer (score -1):

For the HTML/CSS part, depending on what exactly you are dealing with you may be fine making two different `<div>`'s for mobile and non-mobile resolutions, then just apply the style to the mobile viewport `<div>`. (similar to how mobile navbars are often created)